# Query statement that loops through unique ID's in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query statement that finds time gaps in my data set. It works great except that I have 100's of unique ID's I need to run it through. Rather than manually entering the SerialNum, is there a way to run this query statement through each SerialNum in the table? I'm thinking it needs to be a for each loop but don't know how to set that up.

```
    WITH ordered AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateYearAndJulian) rn
    FROM table
    WHERE SerialNum = '040142'
    )
SELECT o1.SerialNum SerialNum1, o1.DateYearAndJulian DateYearAndJulian1, o2.SerialNum SerialNum2, o2.DateYearAndJulian DateYearAndJulian2, DATEDIFF(hh, o1.DateYearAndJulian, o2.DateYearAndJulian) diff
FROM ordered o1 JOIN ordered o2
    ON o1.rn + 1 = o2.rn
WHERE DATEDIFF(hh, o1.DateYearAndJulian, o2.DateYearAndJulian) > 13
```

The result looks like:

```
040142  2018-01-07 22:00:00.0000000 040142  2018-01-16 00:00:00.0000000 194
040142  2019-12-09 16:00:00.0000000 040142  2019-12-10 18:00:00.0000000 26
040142  2020-01-10 22:00:00.0000000 040142  2020-01-12 04:50:00.0000000 30
040142  2018-08-18 23:00:00.0000000 040142  2018-08-21 03:00:00.0000000 52
```

Comment: Can you explain what "time gap" means in this context?  What is the query supposed to be doing?

Comment: The query finds gaps greater than 13hr between consecutive times for a serial number. I will include the headers for the results table I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       DATEDIFF(hour, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) as diff_hours
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(DateYearAndJulian) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNum ORDER BY DateYearAndJulian) as prev_DateYearAndJulian
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) > 13
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I did forget to include that I need to include a where statement for only serial numbers that are active. The active status is in another table though. I did an inner join but I'm getting some errors with the code you wrote. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: `SELECT *,
       DATEDIFF(hour, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) as diff_hours
FROM (SELECT *,
             LAG(DateYearAndJulian) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNum ORDER BY DateYearAndJulian) as prev_DateYearAndJulian
      FROM Collars INNER JOIN ANIMALS ON ANIMALS.ID = Collars.SerialNum
     ) Collars
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) > 13
AND ANIMALS.Status ='Active'`

Comment: @James . . . That information should be in the *question* not a comment.  This answers the question as phrased.